# What is the purpose of using Unit of work pattern? What is its relation with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

if it is already implemented in db context then why we need to implement it explicitly?

Comment: I can't decide if I'm supposed to be helping you with a job interview or a homework assignment.  If I'm wrong, go ahead an post the code you are having issues with, and I'd be happy to help!

Comment: This is a good questiion,  since many programmers implement a kind of repository pattern on top of Entity Framework, but EntityFramework implements already UoW pattern. And there is no need to implement it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF implements UoW and Repository patterns. The DbContext is the UoW. The DbSets are the repositories.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx Where it expressly states that EF implements these patterns.

The purpose of unit of work is to maintain data integrity.

Comment: In all fairness, "maintain data integrity" is _technically correct_, but not really a meaningful explanation to those who do not know the explanation yet. A more elaborate explanation would be that a unit of work enables transactional operations _across multiple entities types_. Without a UoW, you would have to commit a parent entity before you start committing its children, which may be an issue if an issue in one of the children should result in the parent not being committed either.

Answer (score 1):

Think of an EF Repository as the functionality required to manage a specific entity.  Think of UnitOfWork as a collection of Repositories that are related.

For example, take Orders, LineItems, Products, Locations, Inventory

When you add a product to a LineItem of an Order, you want to reduce the available product.  All of these tables (Order, LineItems, Inventory) should be updated together or not at all (in SQL Server-speak, that is a transaction).  UoW is the pattern that allows for multiple entities to be updated *before* any of them commit.  Anything fails and it is all rolled back, protecting your data integrity.

Better?

Answer (score -1):

The pattern make it easier to maintain the source code and you can easily add new database services or change Dbcontex in just one place. But it depends of the project you are working with , if you have a small project use whatever you want , but in large projects you need to add many patterns to make the development easy!

Comment: The purpose of UnitOfWork is not to make source easier to maintain. The purpose is to maintain the integrity of data by encapsulating a transaction.